# Gatsby source WordPress with ACF null field errors in build but not development

Tags: wordpress, build, gatsby, advanced-custom-fields

The following example is with an object containing data from an ACF Repeater field query using Gatsby and WPGraphQL

**Works in *gatsby develop* but not in *gatsby build*:**

```
const IndexPage = ({data}) => {

//this  ACF text field works in both build and development:
console.log(data.wpPage.homepagefields.contact.line1)      

//this fails in build only
console.log(data.wpPage.homepagefields.brands[0].logo.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid.src)
console.log(data.wpPage.homepagefields.services[0])

useEffect(()=>{

}, [])`
```

I tried moving the console.log errors

***Works in both *gatsby develop* but not in *gatsby build*:***

```
const IndexPage = ({data}) => {

//this  ACF text field works in both build and development:
console.log(data.wpPage.homepagefields.contact.line1)    

useEffect(()=>{

    console.log(data.wpPage.homepagefields.brands[0].logo.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid.src)
    console.log(data.wpPage.homepagefields.services[0])
    
}, [])
```

**Same build error (brands resolves as null) arises when trying to access these properties within return():**

```
  return (
    <main className={classes.homepage}>
        <div className={classes.homepage__container}>
           <h1 style={{color:"white"}}>{data.wpPage.homepagefields.contact.line1}</h1>
           <img src={data.wpPage.homepagefields.brands[0].logo.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid.src}></img>
        </div>
    </main>
  )
```

***Gatsby build* error:**

[Screen grab of build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOpf7.png)

Maybe i'm missing something in the lifecycle, but it doesn't make sense to me that the repeater data isn't available until the component has been mounted.

Has anyone experienced the same/similar here?

Comment: `brands` it's always null? Even moving forward and backward through the site?

Comment: This was exactly it,  I didn't realise I still had an additional page which was redundant :/  Thanks for jogging my memory on that

Answer (score 1):

Found the culprit,   after re-installing/updating all gatsby plugis I found that I just had another page which didn't have any custom fields associated with it.

I never loaded that page in develop mode hence why I wasn't getting the errors.

Note to self, make a template specific to the homepage.